# Configure Spring interceptor for controllers only

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to configure a Spring interceptor for controllers only in the following way. For the beginning I want to exclude all the requests starting with `/swagger`. I try to do it in the following way:

```
registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/swagger**");
```

However, interceptor gets fired. Where is a mistake?

Maybe, there is an alternative solution with @ControllerAdvice. But I need to get request headers, so I guess it doesn't fit my needs.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"/swagger*/**"` or `"/swagger*"` instead of `"/swagger**"`

Comment: I tried the second approach, but it doesn't work. The first one too, I've just tried it. I solved my problem in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the following way:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void token(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // getting headers and setting the attribute in the request
        request.setAttribute("theAttribute", new SomeObject());
    }
}
```

And then I get the request attribute in a controller this way:

```
public void someMethod(@RequestAttribute("theAttribute") SomeObject someObject) {
    // some logic goes here
}
```

P.S. And one more note. If you're using `Swagger` you'll get into the trouble as `Swagger` will consider this attribute as controller method parameter. To ignore it you can use the following snapshot of configuration:

```
.ignoredParameterTypes(SomeObject.class);
```